# Substr on an array element if not empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, substr

Hei, I have an array containing some empty strings and some strings with content.

I want to slice down the first 5 letters of those which are not empty strings, and put them into a new array. I also want to keep the empty ones.

example:

```
myArray = [ "","","123456789","","",""];
var newArray = ["","","12345","","",""]
```

I tried with for loop with if inside if the myArray[i] is empty then don't do substr(), but I get an error that it is not a function.

I actually don't need to put it into a new array, I just want to put the myArray(i).subsrt(5) value into a splice(), but then I get the error:

> VM750:82 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined

Comment: `[ "","","123456789","","",""].map(e => e.substr(0, 5))` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 with `array.map`

```
myArray = [ "","","123456789","","",""];
var newArray = myArray.map((s) => s.substr(0, 5))
```

Comment: glad, to help you. please accept if you can.. @BalázsOrbán

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what your exact problem is without seeing all of your code, but here is a for loop that goes over all the elements in the first array and takes the first 5 or fewer characters of each string to insert into a new array.

```
myArray = [ "","","123456789","","",""];
var newArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    newArray.push(myArray[i].substr(0,5));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

exactly what @le_m says:

```
myArray = [ "","","123456789","","",""];
var newArray = myArray.map(e => e.substr(0, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use substr for non-empty items:

Like this:

```
myArray = [ "","","123456789","","",""];
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    temp = myArray[i];
    if (temp && temp != "")
      myArray[i] = temp.substr(0, 5);
    else
      myArray[i] = "";
}
```